# Remove left sidebar through coding

Tags: magento-1.7, blocks, layout, layered-navigation

How to remove the left sidebar based on some condition written in block?
I have to use the same layout xml file. Based on a condition, need to remove a block through coding. 
section need to be removed:

```
 <reference name="left">
   <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
 </reference>
```

I tried with below code.

```
Mage::app()->getLayout()->unsetBlock('left.catalog.leftnav');
```

I didn't get any error but left sidebar still there. can anyone help me? Thanks.

1. I cant access controller. If i have access for controller, then i can easily do in layout rendering section. So i added my work as module and created block. Now I need to change layout / remove left sidebar.
2. Or is It possible to change the layout xml from block? Because i have condition statement in block. so i can choose the layout based on the condition.

Can anyone help me to fix this? Thanks

Comment: Try with `Mage::app()->getLayout()->unsetBlock('left');`

Comment: @Su123 Tried but no error and also block still exist.

Comment: <remove name='catalog.leftnav'/>

Comment: Mage::app()->getLayout()->getUpdate()->addUpdate("<remove name=\"left\"/>");

Comment: @Su123 I have placed your code in block function. Still it not working. Can you tell me where should i add?

Comment: If you can move the logic into a controller action try it there. `$this->loadLayout();Mage::app()->getLayout()->getUpdate()->addUpdate("<remove name=\"left\"/>");$this->renderLayout();`

Answer (score 3):

If you do not want to use an observer what you could do is rewrite the block `Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_View` and override the function `_toHtml` so that it performs the conditional check you want.

```
protected function _toHtml() {
    if (your conditional check) {
        return '';
    }
    return parent::_toHtml();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try to listen some event like `controller_action_layout_load_before`  and you will get layout object like

`$update = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout()->getUpdate();`

now you can remove/unset the block

Comment: I want to do in block not in controller. is there anyway?

Comment: This is not in controller.Its an observer event

Comment: I'm new magento. I dont know where to implement your code. I can't access the controller. So i'm just doing in block and calling block in layout. Can you explain more about your answer. how to add event listener etc..,

Comment: Can't you do it using xml ?